# VSCode shows different Pylint errors in editor mouseover versus problems pane

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

As a newish user of VSCode (ver. 1.27.2) I am trying to run Pylint (v. 2.1.1 on Python 3.6) with many of the extra checkers enabled like the [design checker](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/extensions.html#design-checker) but even though the errors show up on the mouseovers in the editor window, they are not listed in the problems pane. In the image below you can see at least 3 in the mouseover yet only 2 in the problems pane. (There is actually a total of 5 in the editor while still only 2 in the problems pane.) I have `"python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,` in my user settings and also I am sending the extra checkers in my user settings `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint.extensions.mccabe"],` but there seems to be some setting that I am missing that I assume would correctly display the same errors seen in the mouseovers in the editor. Can anyone help? The ones missing seem to be the 'R' type pylint errors - the refactor types.

[image: Code snippet from Pylint docs showing mouseover of pylint errors that do not show up in the problem pane]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like VSCode's PROBLEMS panel displays error, information and warnings, but not hints. I can't find documentation on this but testing seems to indicate that this is the case. And since Pylint refactor issues default to hints in the VSCode settings, they don't show. Changing that setting to any of those 3 values ends up showing the "hints" in the PROBLEMS panel. I wish I could simply include "hints" in the PROBLEMS panel but I cannot find that setting. This works well enough though.

[image]